# How to debug a binary file with gdb

Tags: firefox, debugging, gdb

I currently have a binary program that usually ends locking up after some time using. I can cause it when clicking on the bar on the right side of the screen and moving it swiftly with mouse's left button.

For instance I am executing such a program with the following command:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/arquivos/Gtk+-3.4.0/lib/:/xorg/X11-1.4.4/lib/:/xorg/Xcb-1.4/lib/:/arquivos/Dbus-1.10.2/lib gdb ./firefox
```

Then already inside gdb, I type "run" and Firefox loads. After some time of use, it locks entirely, as per usual, with the background becoming of solid color.

Gdb told me this:

```
 Thread 6 received signal SIGPIPE, Broken pipe.
 [Switching to Thread 0x7fffe2cbe700 (LWP 5192)]
 0x00007ffff7bbe96f in __libc_send (fd=214, buf=0x7fffd694b000, n=24, flags=0)
at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/send.c:31
31  ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/send.c: No such file or directory.
```

with might be useful or not, I don't know really. My main goal is discover the reason behind the error and fix it. I personally believe the culprit is one of the libraries Firefox is using through LD_LIBRARY_PATH or a conflict between them and system default libraries.

The problems is how to do it.